# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: hparams.json

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I try to implement a model for Continuous and Data-Driven Descriptors (CDDD) from https://github.com/jrwnter/cddd.

I cloned the cddd.git and tried to create the conda environment by using the provided yml file but failed getting several dependency "errors". So I created a new conda environment with the listed prerequisites using the conda pacakging manager.

I then installed the cddd package and downloaded the pretrained model as described in the README file.

The "Testing" of the model was successfull but when I try to run the main model, I get several Warnings and a "FileNotFoundError (please see below). I tried to run the script in different directories...

Would be great if someone could help me out. If some information is missing please let me know.

Many Thanks

```
(cddd) [....@localhost default_model]$ cddd --input ../example/ames.csv --output ../example/ames_descriptors.csv  --smiles_header smiles
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/run_cddd.py:99: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

start preprocessing SMILES...
finished preprocessing SMILES!
start calculating descriptors...
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

W0201 17:27:24.857788 139656752092992 lazy_loader.py:50] 
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/bin/cddd", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main_wrapper())
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/run_cddd.py", line 99, in main_wrapper
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + UNPARSED)
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/run_cddd.py", line 79, in main
    cpu_threads=FLAGS.cpu_threads)
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/inference.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.hparams = create_hparams(flags)
  File "/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/hyperparameters.py", line 119, in create_hparams
    hparams = hparams.parse_json(json.load(open(hparams_file_name)))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/..../miniconda3/envs/cddd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cddd/data/default_model/hparams.json'
```

Comment: I got the script running now, though I don't 100% understand what is going on. It seems that `pip install .` creates an external library from where `cddd --input smiles.smi --output descriptors.csv  --smiles_header smiles` is running the scripts. The downloaded model from `./download_default_model.sh` was not included in the folder stucture of these "external libraries" and so hparams.json contained in the model folder could not be found by the python scripts running in the "external libraries". When I copy the "default model" to the "external library" location it works.

Comment: It also works without all that "external library" stuff by using `python3 run_cddd.py --input smiles.smi --output descriptors.csv  --smiles_header smiles` instead of `cddd --input smiles.smi --output descriptors.csv  --smiles_header smiles`